# Как написать Telegram бота с функцией звонка на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мой заказчик дал мне задание написать телеграм-бота на  python с функцией звонка. Я потратил 2 дня на поиск решения данной задачи, однако не где нету об никакой информации.
Если кто знает как это сделать то напишите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, в моём случае звонки служат в качестве уведомлений. На просторах интернета нашёл данный код(https://mdqinc.com/blog/2018/08/telegram-voip-calls-using-python/). Запустить его не удалось, т.к. проблема с библиотеками. Хотелось бы получить ответ от того, кто знает решение. Думаю смог чем-то помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И не найдёте никакой информации, так как боты не умеют (и не должны) звонить.

Вам нужно ознакомиться с [Telegram VoIP Calls](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/voice-calls) и с [MTProto API](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto). Для Python есть прекрасная реализация MTProto API - фреймворк [Pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram).